# Import from Github : How to fix ImportError

Tags: python, module, pytorch

I want to use the [open source person re-identification library](https://github.com/Cysu/open-reid) in Python

- on Ubuntu 19.04
- with Anaconda
- no CUDA
- in the terminal PyCharm (or not)
- Python version 3.7.3
- PyTorch version 1.1.0

For that I have to follow instruction like on their deposite git :

```
git clone https://github.com/Cysu/open-reid.git
cd open-reid
python setup.py install

python examples/softmax_loss.py -d viper -b 64 -j 2 -a resnet50 --logs-dir logs/softmax-loss/viper-resnet50
```

I receive the following error:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath
import pinvh
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'pinvh'

I have tried to create virtual environments with previous versions of PyTorch (0.4.1, 0.4.0 and 1.0.1) but I always got:

```
  File "examples/softmax_loss.py", line 12, in <module>
    from reid import datasets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reid'
```

I do not know how to fix it.

EDIT :

Hi thanks for the answer, the problem is that the import are like :

```
from reid import datasets
from reid import models
from reid.dist_metric import DistanceMetric
from reid.trainers import Trainer
from reid.evaluators import Evaluator
from reid.utils.data import transforms as T
from reid.utils.data.preprocessor import Preprocessor
from reid.utils.logging import Logger
from reid.utils.serialization import load_checkpoint, save_checkpoint
```

I tried :

```
from ../reid import datasets
```

But I got a

```
File "examples/softmax_loss.py", line 12
from ../reid import datasets
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT 2 :
After re-installing Python 3.7.3 and pytorch 1.1.0 the problem persist with pinvh... I still got this message :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pinvh' from 'sklearn.utils.extmath'
```

If you can tell me how to fix it or try to tell me if it works please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the directory structure is as below:

`/(root)-->|
          |
          |-->reid |--> (contents inside reid)
          |
          |
          |-->examples | -->softmax_loss.py
          |
          |-->(Other  contents in root directory)`

It can be observed that `reid` is not in the same directory as `softmax_loss.py`, but instead in the parent directory.

So, in the file softmax_loss.py, at line number 12 and below, replace `reid` with `../reid`, this looks for the directory reid in the parent directory.

The other method is to use: `import ../reid as R` or any other variable; Then use `from R import datasets`, and so on

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, the problem is that the import are like :

    from reid import datasets
    from reid import models
    from reid.dist_metric import DistanceMetric
    from reid.trainers import Trainer

I tried :

from ../reid import datasets

But I got

File "examples/softmax_loss.py", line 12
from ../reid import datasets
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If you can tell me how to fix it please

Comment: The easier way is to move the file ./examples/softmax_loss.py to it's parent directory ./softmax_loss.py

Comment: The other method is to use:
`import ../reid as R` or any other variable; 
Then use `from R import datasets`, and so on.

Comment: It works thanks you very much ! (I take the easier way)

Answer (score 0):

`utils.extmath.pinvh` was deprecated in scikit-learn version 0.19 and removed in version 0.21. The easy fix is therefore to use an earlier version of scikit-learn.